# Opening a webView hides my native iOS View behing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building a plugin for my ionic 1 app. I am showing native iOS view on one screen. On centre of that native view I am trying to add a webview. But When I add it, the native view gets hide and only I can see a webview.

I am adding webview as

`[topcontroller.view addSubView self.webView];`

Comment: Your webview's frame is same as your native view so it is getting hidden.

Comment: Use Xcode to debug the view hierarchy. This should tell you the size and position of all the views in your app, which should help you figure out why you only see the webview.

Comment: @andlin , I have used Xcode to debug view hierarchy. Lemme explain my problem , View 1 is native ios view which I have developed in objective-C in iOS Platform of my Project. View 2 is ionic View . Now I am playing a video in view 1 (Native iOS) and all of sudden I got a popup which I am showing in ionic, comes. Now it is making 2 views , native iOS view or ionic view and when one view is on top, the other goes behind and invisible automatically. 
What I want is my native view remains there , and ionic view which just has to show in center just comes over native view and keep it visible.